# Drag and select items in canvas and delete selected items

Tags: wpf

I am creating a application in WPF in which i need **select Multiple Items** from a canvas(drag and select) and **Delete** it from that Canvas.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have selected One Element and deleted, but the need is want to select multiple items by dragging and delete those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservableCollection to add all controls to a list of selected controls.